# Is this question mentioning Keras off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions, software

[Image classification with large images in R keras](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394761/image-classification-with-large-images-in-r-keras)

OP mentions keras a couple time, but to their credit, they don't include code. I'd like to answer the question, but I wonder if I should comment first and suggest them to remove any reference to a specific software library, in order to make the question of more general interest. What do you think?

PS I used the plural when referring to the OP, because I didn't want to assume a gender.

Comment: Mentioning a library/package/language is not necessarily a problem, nor even including some code - see the [help/on-topic] under *Programming*. [However I strongly encourage people to avoid using code to convey what they're attempting to do, because it mixes together two different sorts of problems that should be kept separate and one of which would be off topic]

Comment: I am with @gung that "they/their" is acceptable to be inclusive,. as is rewriting to avoid pronouns altogether. "The OP mentions keras a couple of times but creditably doesn't include code"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I closed it, with a comment.  It appears to be asking only about how keras works.  If they edit to clarify a machine learning question, I'll be happy to reopen.

For future reference, you are not obliged to hold off on answering, just because a question may be off topic.  I have answered questions that I voted to close, or to migrate to SO, for example.  I believe I have done this even since I have had the ability to close instantly (i.e., as a moderator, rather than sending it into the review queue).  If you think you can help the OP in the interim, there's no reason not to.  (You can also still comment to provide help, if you want—I've done that too.)  If you are worried about losing reputation in exchange for your efforts, be aware that we don't delete such threads just because they've been closed, and the roomba won't delete them if there's an answer with a positive score.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I think it's appropriate to use "they" in English as a 'common' gender pronoun.